# JQuery fadeOut when the mouse is not moved

Tags: jquery, hover

I have this jQuery code that `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` a child div on it's parent div `hover`. I want the child div to fadeOut after five seconds if the mouse is still hovering on the parent div but the mouse is not moving. And if it starts moving again the child div shows up again. You can see an example of what I mean in this short [20sec video](http://tutorials.stephensangkn.org/video/bring.php): Here is the my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#parent_div").hover(function(){
        $("#child_div").fadeIn(500);
    },
    function(){
        $("#child_div").fadeOut(500);   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `mousemove` event to do this work. When mouse is moving on element, use `fadeIn()` and set a timer using `setTimeout()`. In timer and after multipe seconds use `fadeOut()`.

```js
var timer;
$("#parent").mousemove(function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
    $("#child").fadeIn(500);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#child").fadeOut(500);   
    }, 2000);  
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $("#child").fadeOut(500);
});
```

```css
#parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;    
}

#child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad... But I updated the answer Because I also want the `child_div` to `fadeOut` when I leave the `parent_div` Which Your previous answer have to wait for the `timeOut` to expire before fading out even after leaving the `parent_div`

Comment: @Mohammad, it's unfortunate that you didn't have the correct answer (you were originally using the "hover" event, which didn't produce the correct result) when I posted my answer, otherwise I would have just up-voted yours instead of posting my own. Next time.

Answer (score 2):

A likely better approach is to use the "mousemove" event on the parent instead of the the "hover" event. See the code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var childDiv = $("#child_div").hide() // start with the child hidden
      , throttle
      , fadingIn

    $("#parent_div").mousemove(function(event){
        clearTimeout(throttle) // clear the previous 5 second clock

        if (!fadingIn) { // don't runfadeIn() while the element is fading in
         fadingIn = true
         childDiv.stop(true).fadeIn(500, function () {
                fadingIn = false
            });
        }

        throttle = setTimeout(function () { // create a timer to fade out child
            childDiv.fadeOut(500);
        }, 5000) // wait 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds) until it fades out the child
    });
});
```

```css
#parent_div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #aaa;
    padding: 50px
}

#child_div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent_div">
    <div id="child_div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, it's 2022 (almost) and I'm using this snippet, thx